# FormDataConsumer used with ReferenceArrayInput is not working in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-admin

I want to use FormDataConsumer to be able to get an array depending on another array:

```
                <ReferenceInput label="Tipus" source="type" reference="categories" validate={ required() } >
                    <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
                </ReferenceInput>
                <FormDataConsumer>
                    {({formData, ...rest}) => {
                        console.log(formData)
                        <ReferenceArrayInput source={formData.type} reference="categories" {...rest}>
                            <SelectArrayInput optionText="subcategories.name" />
                        </ReferenceArrayInput>
                    }}
                </FormDataConsumer>
```

This gives me a syntax error, which I don't really understand why.

[image: Syntax Error]

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `return (<ReferenceArrayInput source={formData.type} ... )`